# How to debug Java Desktop Application with Ant Script?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am compiling codes and generating jar of my desktop application. But I could not manage to debug codes. I want to put breakpoints and proceed step by step using Eclipse F6 and F5 functions. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for your help? 
My ant script is below:

```
<project name="R - 09 - tester">

<property name="app.name" value="Tester" />
<property name="app.version" value="2.0" />
<property name="dir.root" value="C:/.../trunk" />
<property name="dir.devel" value="${dir.root}/devel" />
<property name="dir.3rdparty" value="${dir.devel}/3rdparty" />
<property name="dir.deploy" value="${dir.root}/deploy" />
<property name="dir.binary" value="${dir.deploy}/bin" />
<property name="dir.class" value="${dir.deploy}/class" />


<property name="jar.xmlbeans" value="${dir.3rdparty}/xmlbeans/xbean.jar" />
<property name="jar.modelmesi" value="${dir.binary}/Model-Mesi-2.0.jar" />
<property name="jar.mesiapi" value="${dir.binary}/Mesi-API-2.0.jar" />
<property name="jar.mesimessages" value="${dir.binary}/Mesi-Messages-2.0.jar" />
<property name="jar.javaFX" value="${dir.3rdparty}/javafx/jfxrt.jar" />

<target name="init.property">
    <property name="manifest.created.by" value="..." />
    <property name="manifest.implementation.title" value="...." />
    <property name="manifest.implementation.vendor" value="..." />
    <property name="jar.mainclass" value="main.ApplicationMain" />
    <mkdir dir="${dir.class}" />
</target>

<target name="init.application" depends="init.property">
    <mkdir dir="${dir.class}/${app.name}" />
   <echo message="(OUTPUT) Application JAR File Name: ${app.name}-${app.version}.jar" />

</target>

<target name="clean.build" description="Clean Created Build Files" depends="init.property">
    <delete dir="${dir.class}/${app.name}" />
    <delete file="${dir.binary}/${app.name}-${app.version}.jar" />
</target>

<target name="clean.all" description="Clean Created All Files" depends="clean.build">
    <delete dir="bin" />
    <delete dir=".codepro" />
    <delete dir=".sonar" />
</target>

<target name="compile.application" depends="init.application">
    <!-- compile files on the src path -->
    <copy file="src/SceneStyle.css" todir="${dir.class}/${app.name}"/>
    <javac debug="true" srcdir="src" destdir="${dir.class}/${app.name}" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${jar.xmlbeans}" />
            <pathelement location="${jar.mesiapi}" />
            <pathelement location="${jar.modelmesi}" />
            <pathelement location="${jar.mesimessages}" />
            <pathelement location="${jar.javaFX}" />
            <fileset dir="${dir.3rdparty}/jreport">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="build" description="Build the Application" depends="compile.application">
    <tstamp />
    <!-- needed for TODAY -->
    <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpaths" jarfile="${dir.binary}/${app.name}-${app.version}.jar">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${jar.xmlbeans}" />
            <pathelement location="${jar.mesiapi}" />
            <pathelement location="${jar.modelmesi}" />
            <pathelement location="${jar.mesimessages}" />
            <pathelement location="${jar.javaFX}" />
            <fileset dir="${dir.3rdparty}/jreport">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>

    <jar destfile="${dir.binary}/${app.name}-${app.version}.jar" basedir="${dir.class}/${app.name}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Created-By" value="${manifest.created.by}" />
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
            <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${jar.mainclass}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpaths}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${manifest.implementation.vendor}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${manifest.implementation.title}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${app.version}-b${build.number}" />
        </manifest>

    </jar>
</target>

<target name="rebuild" description="Rebuild the Application" depends="clean.build,build" />

<target name="run" description="Run the Application" depends="build">
    <java jar="${dir.binary}/${app.name}-${app.version}.jar"/>

</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final state of antscript is specified below:

```
<target name="compile">
    <javac  srcdir="src" destdir="${dir.class}/${app.name}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" >
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="..." />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="debug" description="Debug the Application" depends="compile">
    <java jar="${dir.binary}/${app.name}-${app.version}.jar" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5555" />
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should enable remote debugging using `<java>` tag.

```
<java ....>
 <jvmarg value="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5555"/>
</java>
```

Now run your ant script. It will start java process and wait until you connect with your debugger to porr `5555`.

If you do not want to wait change `suspend=y` to `suspend=n`.

Comment: I have corrected my run task like below and put a breakpoint but Eclipse did not stop in the breakpoint. 
<target name="run" description="Run the Application" depends="build">
    <java jar="${dir.binary}/${app.name}-${app.version}.jar">
<jvmarg value="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5555"/>
</java>
</target>

Comment: Does Eclipse connect to remote process or fails to connect?

Comment: There is no error or information related with connection failed or success. how can I control this connection?

Comment: Still problem is going on.. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I have create new debug configuration on Eclipse and when I click debug button Eclipse says that "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused..."

Comment: Have you set correct port to the Eclipse debug configuration? It must be the same port that you write in ant script.

Comment: Yes both of them is 5555

Comment: I wonder that my ant target that is described in the first comment is correct? can you check it? thanks for your help

Comment: When JVM starts with enabled debug it prints to STDOUT `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5555`. Since your debug is configured to suspend it should print this phrase and freeze until you connect with debugger. Does it happen when you run ant script?

Comment: It says "Waiting for vm to connect at port 5555" in the Progress tab When I start debug and nothing is performed and after some time an error is occurred related with server connection.

Comment: Does your debugger connect to ant process successfully?

Comment: Sorry..I am new in antscript how can I check it? Thanks.

Comment: Run ant script. It stops and waits for debuggger to connect. Then connect with debugger and see if it complains that it cannot connect or says that it is connected.

Comment: I have performed your steps but there is no any connection status in console and progress tab. But I realised that when I closed the program, an error is showed console tab related with: <jvmarg value="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5555"/> It says Cause: The name is undefined, Action: Check the spelling ...

Comment: After I separated jvmargs that is specified above It began to listen the port. Thanks.

Comment: Well, nice to know it.